# pass a function belonging to a service containing an observable to a child component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a project in which I have many Models (ingredients, products, medals), and a service for each. My problem is I want to create a list-component generic that takes in parameters a 'mode' variable corresponding to a name of one of my models.

With this 'mode' variable, I want to set up variables fonctions likes :

```
let str = `this.${this.mode}Service.${this.mode}CollectionLengthById(this.userId).subscribe({ 
      next : (res : number) => {
         ${this.nbOfItems} = res.toString() + ' ' + this.mode
}
})`;
```

After several attempts and a lot of research I found the method eval(), but she is very dangerous not secure, then, I found this way :

```
let str = `console.log('toto')`;

let func = new Function(str);

func();
```

This code works but when I want to call a function in a service or an observables, I get an error :

```
let str = let str = `this.ingredientService.consoleLogTest()`;

let func = new Function(str);

func();
```

The Error message :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'consoleLogTest')
    at eval (eval at ngOnInit (list.component.ts:118:16), <anonymous>:3:24)
    at ListComponent.ngOnInit (list.component.ts:119:5)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2498:22)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2467:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2418:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12026:21)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:13039:17)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12035:9)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:13085:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:11801:9)
```

If anyone has an idea, I'm interested.

Answer (score 0):

i believe this is because you don't have any method called `consoleLogTest` in your service file called `ingredientService`.
check to be sure it exist or there is no typo in the name.
if you can post your `ingredientService` file code, that will help.